# mod_rewrite for mobile version

Tags: apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have assemled these rules from various sources, do any of you see any pitfalls?

I'm using this to setup a mobile version of an ZendFramework powered website.

```
# You ofcourse need this to start the magic, and mod_rewrite enabled ;)
RewriteEngine On

# iOS redirection.
# Make sure the URL hasn't already been rewritten internally
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
# Make sure we don't redirect links from mobile to default (web) back to mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
# Don't use this Cond if you want direct requests on 'domain.tld' go to mobile
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Mobile.*Safari
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [R,L]

# ZendFramework redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I'm not a mod_rewrite expert, so what does [R,L] and [NC,L] mean?

**Update**

Just tested this with an iPad, and it don't redirect in it. But again, i guess the mobile version would not be needed for iPads.. What do you think?

**Update on the update**

Hmm.. just realised that going directly to `http://www.domain.com/` from iPhone don't work, it has though. Adding something to the query like `http://www.domain.com/tracker` correctly redirects to `http://www.domain.com/m/tracker` - So maybe this is the reason the iPad didn't show the mobile site (and i don't have the iPad at hands right now).

**Third update**

Had another go at the problem with mobile website not showing when going directly to `http://www.domain.com/`. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` was the problem.

Comment: [NC] stand for No Case, case-insensitive. [L] stands for Last, don't process any more rules. [R] stands for redirect, force an actual redirect back to the browser. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ This website has a quite extensive RegEx for detecting mobile devices. I have replaced my `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Mobile.*Safari` with it. The previous Cond only targets Apple devices.

The complete mod_rewrite from [detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile [R,L]
```

I think you should spice it up with one of my Cond's above, i think it may be prone to end up in and infinite loop - havent tested.