# Redirect Desktop Internal Pages to Correct Mobile Internal Pages with Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, http-status-code-302

I have built a Mobile site in a sub-domain.
I have successfully implemented the redirect 302 from:

```
www.domain.com to m.domain.com in htaccess.
```

What I'm looking to achieve now it to redirect users from:

```
www.domain.com/internal-page/ > 302 > m.domain.com/internal-page.html
```

Notice that **URL name for desktop and mobile is not the same**.
The code I'm using looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Mobile Redirect
# Verify Desktop Version Parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ViewFullSite=true(&|$)

# Set cookie and expiration
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.domain.com:60]

# Prevent looping
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.domain.com$

# Define Mobile agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]

# Verify if not already in Mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.

# We need to read and write at the same time to set cookie
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ViewFullSite=true(&|$) 

# Verify that we previously haven't set the cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect the users to the Mobile Homepage
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain.com [R]
RewriteRule $/internal-page/ http://m.domain.com/internal-page.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you have two `RewriteRule` lines which I believe should be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^\/?$ http://m.domain.com [R=302]
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)\/?$ http://m.domain.com/$1.html [R=302,L]
```

The `^\/?(.*)\/?$` means give me a string that starts at the beginning (**^**) and gives me all characters (**(.*)**) until the end (**$**) without the trailing/beginning (**/**) if there is one (**?**).

The `http://m.domain.com/$1.html` means that if the address is `http://www.domain.com/internal-page/` then it becomes `http://m.domain.com/internal-page.html`.

The `[R=302,L]` should mean a 302 redirect (**R=302**) and the last rewrite (**L**), so no other rewrites can occur on our URL.

**EDIT:**

I believe that in the case of your *RewriteRules* the first one was redirecting to `http://m.domain.com` in the event that the URL was just the domain, but if there was anything else then the second rewrite was failing because it was not actually literally `/internal-page/` and you needed a regex variable to put into the new URL.

**EDIT (2):**

To redirect to each mobile page from a specific desktop page:

```
RewriteRule ^\/foo\/?$ http://m.domain.com/bar.html [R=302]
RewriteRule ^\/hello\/?$ http://m.domain.com/world.html [R=302]
```

The (**/?**) means that a **/** is optional in that position and the (**^**) denotes beginning and (**$**) denotes ending in this case (the **^** can also be used to indicated something like `[^\.]` which means anything ***except*** a period).

Just put how ever many of those that you need in a row to do the redirecting and that should do the trick. To make sure there are no misconceptions, the first line would mean that `http://www.domain.com/foo/` would become `http://m.domain.com/bar.html` and because the trailing slash is made optional `http://www.domain.com/foo` (notice the trailing forward slash is absent) would also redirect to `http://m.domain.com/bar.html`.

You can play with the syntax a bit to customize it, but hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction.  If you need anything else, let me know, I'll do my best to assist.

I don't want to sound like a broken record or anything, but I feel that I could not, in good conscience, end this edit without pointing out that modifying the mobile site would be a much better way to do this. If it is not possible or you feel that a few static redirects are not a big deal versus modifying some pages, then I totally understand, but here are a few things for you to think about:

If the mobile site and desktop site are in separate folders then the exact same name scheme can be used for both making the Rewrites simpler and meaning that as new pages/content are added you will not need more Rewrite statements (making more rewrites means you have to create the new pages and then you have to create the redirects.  that's extra work and more files which require your attention.)

If the mobile site is actually hosted from the same directory as the desktop site, then changing the files for one or the other so it becomes something like `/desktop-foo/` or `/d-foo/` then it is very easy to make the rewrite (redirect) go to something like `/m-foo.html`.  You could forego modifying the desktop pages and make `/foo/` become `/m-foo.html` and make all your mobile versions begin with an 'm'.

The third option that comes to mind is the most difficult and time consuming, depending on the content of the site, but it is a pretty cool one and ultimately would make the site the easiest to work on (after the initial work, of course).  It is quite possible to use the same page for desktop, mobile, tablet, etc without the use of mod_rewrite or separate pages.  Things like media queries in your CSS would allow you to change the look of the page depending on what the client is viewing it from.  I came across a tutorial on the subject earlier which used media queries and the max-width of the screen to determine how the page should look.  This would require a good bit of work now, but could save some hassle down the road as well as being an interesting learning experience if you are up to the challenge.

Again, sorry that this veered off topic at the end there, but I got the impression from your original question and your responses that you might find the alternatives interesting if you haven't already considered and dismissed them and that even if the alternatives do not interest you that you aren't going to be like some people and respond with, "Hey, $*%& you, buddy! I asked for Rewrites not all that other garbage!"  I hope you take it as nothing more than what it is intended to be...helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply txpeaceofficer09, but the problem is that the internal pages in the Mobile site, do not correspond to the Desktop URLs. Meaning we can have /internal-page/ > 302 > /other-internal-page-name/

Comment: Okay you are in pretty bad shape then. You will have to create rewrites for every possible page to have something like http://www.domain.com/foo/ become http://m.domain.com/bar.html if you insist on using rewrites.

Comment: Alternatively, change the mobile site so the pages correlate to the desktop site in some way so a regex rewrite would work.

Comment: I thought so @txpeaceofficer09 ...can you point me in the right direction in writing a rewrite for every single page that validates the mobile agents and checkes the cookie as well?. I know its a bit of a pain, but since its a Mobile site, the number of pages is not more than 10, so it shouldn't take long, thanks for the help

Comment: I really appreciate your hel, and i totally understand why you suggested other alternatives. nevertheless, since we are talking about a Mobile site, I would like URLs to be more condensed, whereas desktop are longer.

Tha being said, I have tried adding what you suggested with no luck. I's pasting my htaccess file part to make things easier, and luckily we can sort this.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ViewFullSite=true(&|$)  
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.ygeia.es:60]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone"[NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ViewFullSite=true(&|$)   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.ygeia.es/ [R=302]  
RewriteRule ^\/psicologia\/?$ http://m.ygeia.es/psicologia.html   [R=302]

Comment: I'll test some redirects on one of my sites and see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Okay, I tested the rewrites on one of my sites and they all performed flawlessly.  I went to http://m.ygeia.es/psicologia.html and got a 404 error. You can't redirect to something that doesn't exist or you get a 404 error.  Make sure the file is there and then it should work. _crosses fingers_.

Comment: Additionally, you could remove the `RewriteRule ^$ m.ygeia.es [R=302]` and try `RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ http://m.ygeia.es/$1 [R=302,L]` as the last redirect and change the previous **[R=302]** to **[R=302,L]** as well. This _should_ mean that if all the static redirects fail that it will try whatever url it is given. and the (**L**) means _last_ so each Rewrite that succeeds should make itself the last rewrite and not let any others execute.  That would prevent the last "catch all" Rewrite from overriding our static ones if a static one succeeds.

Comment: This is frustrating, I have changed the RewriteRule for the homepage and it doesn't work. I hace tried the following and it doesn't work.# Redirigir ahora al sitio Mobile
RewriteRule ^\/psicologia\/?$ m.ygeia.es/psicologia-individual.html [R=302]
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ http://m.ygeia.es/$1 [R=302,L]

Comment: You forgot the **L** in the first `RewriteRule`.  Without putting L in the first one then it will Rewrite and then the next one will Rewrite and it has a regex.  I don't see how it would hurt it, but if you were to change that last one to something that might affect it then you would be wondering what happened when other pages started going to the wrong places.  Other than that I'm not seeing a problem.  I'll have to duplicate your scheme locally this evening and play with it so I can find the issue and hopefully the solution.

Comment: Thanks @txpeaceofficer09 I added the L as you mentioned and still no luck. I really dont know what is wrong as you are nto having problems... I'm not even being able of sending every request to the Mobile homepage, because as soon as I use the following it fails to redirect, and even render styles and images: RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ http://m.ygeia.es/$1 [R=302,L]

Comment: I will be home tonight and I will mirror your config and try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Okay, so I took another look at your config and the wordpress stuff looks like it might be an issue. It basically says, "If the requested file doesn't exist redirect to the home page (/index.php)." This also has an **[L]** attribute so all the other rewrite stuff is ignored once that succeeds.  Maybe I'm just sleep deprived, but that could be an issue.  Also check out [this](http://www.detectmobilebrowsers.com) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218354/mod-rewrite-for-mobile-version). Might help. Let me know.

Comment: I have tried removing both L attributes and still doesn't work. I also checked both links you sent me and tested a few things with no luck ;(

Comment: The entire section for WordPress is not needed and could be replaced by `RewriteEngine on`.  All that section is supposed to do is keep users from seeing an error 404 message by sending them back to the main home page.  Personally, I like the 404 so I know what I want is gone and that the site isn't just screwed up.  Failing that though then I would think either your server config is flawed or some of your RewriteCond should be sacrificed to see if we can get it working.  "Back to basics" strip it down to just the `RewriteRules` and see if they work then add `RewriteCond` until it fails.

Comment: Then we will see what is actually causing so many headaches.  If that fails, then the only thing I can offer is alternative solutions to mod_rewrite, because I can't think of anything else to try.  Unless someone with more mod_rewrite experience can offer guidance.

Comment: Thanks @txpeaceofficer09 I will troubleshoot during the weekend and If I have any luck I'll get back with the solution.

Comment: I have successfully placed the 302 redirect from root and internal desktop pages to the Mobile homepage, which is somehow good. Still I haven´t been able to redirect each desktop internal page to it's corresponding Mobile internal page.

Comment: What does the new version look like now?  Perhaps seeing it I can make new suggestions or someone else will come along with some helpful info.